# I'm coding a game in python but ı stuck

Tags: python, dice

Dice game rules: if dice 1 came, turn is on the other player "computer"
if its not, ı can throw again now for earning points. Dice would give as much as what came. Its adding to my points but if 1 cames, ı cant take these points. I should have stopped before 1 cames.
I say yes, (thats enough): ı earn point and the turn is on the computer. İf 1 came, no points for me and the turn is on computer either.
For winn, one of us have to reach point 100. (99 is not win but the last dice is 6 points, that would made 105- still winn)

Can somebody help me with adding computer on my game? I dont know how.

```
from random import randint

run = True
point = 0

while run:
    inp = input("throw dice: ")
   
    if inp == "y":
        dice = randint(1, 7)
        
        if dice != 1:
            point = point + dice
           
            print(dice.__str__() + " came")
            print("your point is: " + point.__str__())
    
        else:
            #1e gelince
            run = False
            
            print("1 came, you cant continue. Your point was: " + point.__str__())
            
    else: 
        #say false to end game
        run = False
       
        print("last point: " + point.__str__())
```

Comment: `dice = randint(1, 7)`: "`random.randint(a, b)` Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b."  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)  the range for `random.randint` is *inclusive*.  I've never heard of a 7 sided die, but I guess you can simulate one on a computer, if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add computer related logic. You can change your algorithm maybe like this:

```py
from random import randint

run = True
computerTurn = False
point = 0
computerPoint = 0

while run:
    if computerTurn:
        dice = randint(1, 7)

        if dice != 1:
            computerPoint += dice
            print(dice.__str__() + " came")
            print("computer point is: " + computerPoint.__str__())
        else:
            print("computer point is: " + computerPoint.__str__())
            print("1 came, your turn!!!")
            computerTurn = False
    else:
        inp = input("throw dice: ")
    
        if inp == "y":
            dice = randint(1, 7)
            
            if dice != 1:
                point = point + dice
            
                print(dice.__str__() + " came")
                print("your point is: " + point.__str__())
        
            else:
                
                print("your point is: " + point.__str__())
                print("1 came, computer turn!!!")
                computerTurn = True

                
        else: 
            #say false to end game
            run = False
        
            print("last point: " + point.__str__())
```

Comment: I applaud including a version of your source complete enough to verify, but I would like to see a discussion about what you changed here and what it fixes, or at least some analysis other than "here, I rewrote your code for you" .  I want to stress that no doubt you found a bug and you fixed it.  What is it?

Comment: I thought that he did not know how to build an algorithm on how to add a simple artificial intelligence and wanted to learn it.
I showed a very simple example of forming ideas for the approach.

Comment: Yes, that was what ı got confused. Thank you both. Now ı see how to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm works fine and you can reuse a lot of the logic for your player turn in the computer turn.

The only thing that needs to be implemented differently for the computer is some sort of logic that helps it decide when to end its own turn so that the game is fun and not purely luck related.

For example, in the below algorithm the computer will roll the dice until it reaches a turnpoints score of >= 20, then the players turn begins.

It would also be a good idea to add a slight delay for the computers dice rolls so you can visually see the progress of its turn as opposed to it instantly flashing across the screen, this can be implemented with the time.sleep() function from time library.

```
from random import randint
import time

run = True
playerturn = True
turnpoints = 0
playerpoints = 0
computerpoints = 0

while run:
    if playerturn:
        inp = input("do you want to throw dice?: (y or n) ")
        if inp == "y":
            dice = randint(1, 7)
            if dice != 1:
                turnpoints = turnpoints + dice
                print(dice.__str__() + " came")
                print("your points for this turn are: " + turnpoints.__str__())
                if (playerpoints + turnpoints) >= 100:
                    playerpoints = playerpoints + turnpoints
                    print("You won the game with a point score of: " + playerpoints.__str__())
                    break
            else:
                print("1 came, you cant continue. Your earned no points this turn. Current Points: " + playerpoints.__str__())
                playerturn = False
                turnpoints = 0
        else:
            playerpoints = playerpoints + turnpoints
            print("You finished the turn. You turn is now over. Current Points: " + playerpoints.__str__())
            playerturn = False
            turnpoints = 0
    else: #computer's turn
        dice = randint(1, 7)
        if dice != 1:
            turnpoints = turnpoints + dice
            print(dice.__str__() + " came")
            print("computer points for this turn are: " + turnpoints.__str__())
            time.sleep(1)
            if (computerpoints + turnpoints) >= 100:
                computerpoints = computerpoints + turnpoints
                print("Computer won the game with a point score of: " + computerpoints.__str__())
                break
            if turnpoints > 20:
                computerpoints = computerpoints + turnpoints
                print("Computers turn is now over. Current Points: " + computerpoints.__str__())
                playerturn = True
                turnpoints = 0
        else:
            playerturn = True
            print("1 came, Computer's turn is over. Computer earned no points this turn. Current Points: " + computerpoints.__str__())
            turnpoints = 0
```

Comment: Making a move for computer is clever, not based pure luck. I understand that part and turning sides. Just, How did you said computer when to stop? While ı was working something else, it kept trying until 1 came and completly stop. Also, thank you for the giving time to showing the progress. It looks all good.

Comment: understand. Thats is explanatory. I'm new to this site, ı accept yours. Thanks for your help.  There is a lot of things to add game.